# Map values in dataframe based on condition using a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I have the following dictionary

```
dict_map = {
    'Anti' : {'Drug':('A','B','C')},
    'Undef': {'Drug':'D','Name':'Type X'},
    'Vit ' : {'Name': 'Vitamin C'},
    'Placebo Effect' : {'Name':'Placebo', 'Batch':'XYZ'},
}
```

And the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
        'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06'],
        'Drug': ["A","B","A",np.nan,"D","D"],
        'Name': ['Placebo', 'Vitamin C', np.nan, 'Placebo', '', 'Type X'],
        'Batch' : ['ABC',np.nan,np.nan,'XYZ',np.nan,np.nan],
        
}
```

I have to create a new column, which will used the data of the columns specified in the list to populate

```
cols_to_map = ["Drug", "Name", "Batch"]
```

The end result should look like this

[image]

Note that 'Result' column has 'Anti' filled for first 3 rows despite having 'Vitamin C' and 'Placebo' is column 'Name' this is because 'Anti' comes first in dictionary. How do I achieve this using python? The dict_map can be restructured in anyway to meet this result. I'm not a python pro, I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

First reshape nested dicts for separate values of tuples in nested dicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in dict_map.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        if isinstance(v1, tuple):
            for x in v1:
                d[k1][x] = k
        else:
            d[k1][v1] = k

print (d)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'Drug': {'A': 'Anti', 'B': 'Anti', 
                                      'C': 'Anti', 'D': 'Undef'},
                             'Name': {'Type X': 'Undef', 'Vitamin C': 'Vit ',
                                      'Placebo': 'PPL'}})
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06'],
            'Drug': ["A","B","A",np.nan,
                     "D","D"],
            'Name': ['Placebo', 'Vitamin C', np.nan, 'Placebo', '', 'Type X']
    }
    )
```

Then mapping by dictioanry, prioritized is by order of column in list `cols_to_map`:

```
cols_to_map = ["Drug", "Name"]

df['Result'] = np.nan
for col in cols_to_map:
    df['Result'] = df['Result'].combine_first(df[col].map(d[col]))

print (df)
     ID Drug       Name Result
0  AB01    A    Placebo   Anti
1  AB02    B  Vitamin C   Anti
2  AB03    A        NaN   Anti
3  AB04  NaN    Placebo    PPL
4  AB05    D             Undef
5  AB06    D     Type X  Undef
```

---

```
cols_to_map = [ "Name","Drug"]

df['Result'] = np.nan
for col in cols_to_map:
    df['Result'] = df['Result'].combine_first(df[col].map(d[col]))

print (df)
     ID Drug       Name Result
0  AB01    A    Placebo    PPL
1  AB02    B  Vitamin C   Vit 
2  AB03    A        NaN   Anti
3  AB04  NaN    Placebo    PPL
4  AB05    D             Undef
5  AB06    D     Type X  Undef
```

EDIT:

```
df['Result1'] = df['Drug'].map(d['Drug'])
df['Result2'] = df['Name'].map(d['Name'])
print (df)
     ID Drug       Name Result1 Result2
0  AB01    A    Placebo    Anti     PPL
1  AB02    B  Vitamin C    Anti    Vit 
2  AB03    A        NaN    Anti     NaN
3  AB04  NaN    Placebo     NaN     PPL
4  AB05    D              Undef     NaN
5  AB06    D     Type X   Undef   Undef
```

Comment: Thank you, but 'Undef' should be in only row 5 since only that row has 'D' in column Drug and 'Type X' in column Name and 'Anti' has to be on rows 0,1,2 since it meets the first condition specified in the dictionary

Comment: @Fazli - Unfortunately not understand why.

Comment: @Fazli - first, second and last rows match both conditions (Drug, Name), third, fifth mach `Name`, fourth match `Drug`. Why is there `NaN` ?

Comment: So if it meets the first condition and gets mapped then no need to check for other conditions (can this be done by creating the new column with nans and use fillna in a for loop) and there's NaN for row 4 since there isn't case for which it should be mapped if Drug is D and Name is ""

Comment: @Fazli Check EDIT. In Result1 is mapped `Drug`, so only `index=3` is NaN, if mapping `Name` to `Result2` get NaN for `2,4`. So why is replaced index=4 to `NaN` in final column?

Comment: I don't understand your final sentence

Comment: I still not understand NaN value, so I add mapping each column separately in lat part of answer in EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Since the relation between dict and the expected result is quite intricate, I would use a function to apply on your DataFrame. This saves us from manipulating the dictionary:

```
def get_result(row):
    result = np.nan
    for k,v in dict_map.items():
        if row['Name'] in v.values():
            result = k
        if row['Name'] and type(row['Drug']) == str and 'Drug' in v.keys() and row['Drug'] in v['Drug']:
            return k
    return result


df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_result(row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ID Drug       Name Result
0  AB01    A    Placebo   Anti
1  AB02    B  Vitamin C   Anti
2  AB03    A        NaN   Anti
3  AB04  NaN    Placebo    PPL
4  AB05    D               NaN
5  AB06    D     Type X  Undef
```

Following the update of your question I changed the function to be generic. I'm not quite sure it would cover all your cases though since your output doesn't change much with the new column:

```
col_to_maps = ["Drug", "Name", "Batch"]

def get_result(row, dict_map):
    result = np.nan
    for k,v in dict_map.items():
        for i,col in enumerate(col_to_maps[:-1]):    
            if type(v)==dict:
                if str(row[col]) and \
                 all(str(row[other_col])
                     and (not(str(other_col) in v.keys()) and str(col) in v.keys() and str(row[col]) in v[col]
                          or str(other_col) in v.keys() and str(row[other_col]) in v[other_col]
                          )
                     for other_col in col_to_maps[i+1:]
                    ):
                    return k 
            elif str(row[col]) in v:
                result = k
    return result


df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_result(row, dict_map), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ID Drug       Name Batch          Result
0  AB01    A    Placebo   ABC            Anti
1  AB02    B  Vitamin C   NaN            Anti
2  AB03    A        NaN   NaN            Anti
3  AB04  NaN    Placebo   XYZ  Placebo Effect
4  AB05    D              NaN             NaN
5  AB06    D     Type X   NaN           Undef
```

Comment: If there anyway I can do it without hardcoding the column names and instead getting the columns of interest from the list cols_to_map ? Because there might instances in which there are more than 2 variables involved

Comment: Could you give an example with a third column? including changes to the dictionary and expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question above

Comment: ok I'm not sure I entirely grasped your requirements but I updated my answer. check it out!